# How to change a text with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an `h1` with id of `toptitle` that is dynamically created, and I am not able to change the HTML.
It will have a different title depends on a page. Now when it is Profile, I want to change it to `New word` with jQuery.

```
<h1 id="toptitle">Profile</h1> // Changing only when it is Profile  
// to
<h1 id="toptitle">New word</h1>
```

Note: If the text is `Profile`, then change it to `New word`.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#toptitle').text(function(i, oldText) {
        return oldText === 'Profil' ? 'New word' : oldText;
    });
});
```

This only replaces the content when it is `Profil`.  See [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text) in the jQuery API.

Answer (score 137):

This should work fine (using [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text):

```
$("#toptitle").text("New word");
```

Answer (score 16):

Something like this should work

```
var text = $('#toptitle').text();
if (text == 'Profil'){
    $('#toptitle').text('New Word');
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Could do it with `:contains()` selector as well:

```
$('#toptitle:contains("Profil")').text("New word");
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/xPRzr/

Answer (score 10):

### Cleanest

Try this for a clean approach.

```
var $toptitle = $('#toptitle');

if ( $toptitle.text() == 'Profile' ) // No {} brackets necessary if it's just one line.  
  $toptitle.text('New Word');
```

Answer (score 8):

```
$('#toptitle').html('New world');
```

or

```
$('#toptitle').text('New world');
```

Answer (score 5):

Pretty straight forward to do:

```
$(function() {
  $('#toptitle').html('New word');
});
```

The html function accepts html as well, but its straight forward for replacing text.

Answer (score 5):

**In my case i have stored the new Value in the var altText*

```js
$('#toptitle').text(altText);
```

*
**And it Worked**