# JQuery won't change text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am very new to JQuery and I'm not sure how to better describe this problem other than that the text in the

tag won't change and this is modeled after the example on the start page of the JQuery site.  The fiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/sojwsuk1

Here is the JQuery code:

```
    function toggle()
    {
        $("p.greeting").html("Goodbye");
    }
```

and the HTML:

```
    <p id="greeting">Hello</p>
    <button onclick="toggle()">Click Me</button>
```

Please forgive the question because I am very new to JQuery and the last time I did javascript was 3 semesters ago!

Thank you for reading.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change a text with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411696/how-to-change-a-text-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `toggle` method should be placed in head, in fiddle that is loaded after html. So use like below to make it in other ways way

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
   $('#greeting').html('GoodBye');
});
```

and also check `bind` (if jQuery < 1.7.2 ) and `delegated events with on method`

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/sojwsuk1/5/

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/bind/) method is the preferred over `bind()` for attaching event handlers to a document. You probably shouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @filoxo Yes you are right. But not sure which version he is going to use. I have seen people still struck with 1.4 :). And I consider not recommending it.

Comment: The demo that the OP linked to is using jQuery 2.1. But still fair enough because I also know of situations where upgrading to later versions isn't possible. Perhaps make a note of that on your answer?

Comment: I tried everyone else's code and Exception's answer was the only one that worked.  How do you make sure fiddle works like that?

Comment: @manFromMidwest Your html code was calling toggle method before toggle itself is created. I suggest you to read `$(document).ready()` to understand why it worked.

Answer (score 2):

greeting is the id of the p tag, you can use:

```
$("#greeting").html("Goodbye");
```

You can learn jquery through this site: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp, the selector of jquery is very likely the selector of css.

Comment: ==> http://www.w3fools.com/ - avoid w3school, why not provide jquery.com selector reference `:)` just an idea!

Comment: Thank you :), jquery.com is the best site to learn jquery.W3shcool is easy to learn some basic knowledge, we can edit the source code and then can see the result,which is good to beginners.

Comment: w3schools is not affiliated with the W3C, however they appear to represent themselves that way, maybe that's a reason not to use them.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p id="greeting">Hello</p>
<button id="test">Click Me</button>

$('#test').click(function(){
    $("#greeting").html("Goodbye");
})

//quick and easy way to do it without the onclick in html tag
```

Here is the JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sojwsuk1/7/

Also just a heads up the selector you use is looking for a class.  If you are trying to select a class you use the ".", if you are looking for ID you use the "#".