# How do i get the experience to add to the previous experience each time monster is slain?

Tags: javascript, type-conversion, nan

it works to a point. If the first monster is killed, it will put "100" in the character experience header span. Now I am trying to figure out how to get it to add 100 each time the player defeats a monster. I have tried many different ways. Below is my codepen link. Please help me with this issue, and explain what is happening. I have made variables with the values of the span in the heading, but the values come up nan. I have tried to parseInt the variables, ive tried Number on the variables. I just cant seem to put it together with my limited knowledge.

```
function test(){
   var plyrInputDmg = $("#charDamageMax").html();
  var plyrDamage = Math.floor(Math.random()*plyrInputDmg)+1;
   $("#charAction").html("Player did " + plyrDamage + "points of damage");
  var newMonsterHP = $("#targetLife").html() - plyrDamage;
  if(newMonsterHP >= 0){
    $("#targetLife").html(newMonsterHP);
  }else{
    $("#targetLife").html('monster is dead');
    $('#charExperience').html("100");//experience is static. It is only good for the first battle. I need to make it add to the previous exp for each monster killed. I have tried many ways but have no success.

  }

}
```

[enter link description here](https://codepen.io/gatehrdy/pen/QQJooG)

[image]

Comment: Please show us some of the "many ways" you've tried.

Comment: Ok, please give me a min. I have to recreate them because once they didnt work, i deleted what i tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change a text with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411696/how-to-change-a-text-with-jquery)

Comment: This is the last method i tried. function test(){
   var plyrInputDmg = $("#charDamageMax").html();
  var plyrDamage = Math.floor(Math.random()*plyrInputDmg)+1;
   $("#charAction").html("Player did " + plyrDamage + "points of damage");
  var newMonsterHP = $("#targetLife").html() - plyrDamage;
  if(newMonsterHP >= 0){
    $("#targetLife").html(newMonsterHP);
  }else{
    $("#targetLife").html('monster is dead');
    var expVal = 100;
    var charDisplayVal = $('#charExperience').html();
    $("#charExperience").html(expVal + charDisplayVal);
  }
  
}

Comment: here is the link with the changes: https://codepen.io/gatehrdy/pen/QQJooG

Comment: you need to parse your string to int before adding them, something like   $("#charExperience").html(expVal + parseInt(charDisplayVal));