# I cannot change the text for html inside jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I haven't used jQuery since a long time, and I have forget a lot of things in it.
I tried to change the element text when an element clicked but it didn't work, I don't know why.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>practice test</h1>
    <h1>practice test</h1>
    <h1>practice test</h1>
    <h1>practice test</h1>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        $("h1").click(() => {
            console.log("event trigered");
            $(this).text("this element is clicked");
        });
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this. where you send the event with the click and then get the target, that is clicked, and then you can edit the content of that with `.text()`

```js
$("h1").click(event => {
  const clickedElement = $(event.target);
  console.log("event trigered");
  clickedElement.text("this element is clicked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>practice test1</h1>
<h1>practice test2</h1>
<h1>practice test3</h1>
<h1>practice test4</h1>
```

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried using html() function instead of text()?
Also, you can check this StackOverflow page, if you'll still have problems with it: [How to change a text with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411696/how-to-change-a-text-with-jquery)