# Replace country code with country with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'd like to replace country abbreviations with country names but can't get it to work - what am I doing wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/f6jq7eht/1/

HTML

```
<div class="country">
        <span class="section-label">Country/Region</span>
        <div>IT</div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
        var text = $(".country div").html();
        text = text.replace('CA', 'Canada')
        text = text.replace('DE', 'Germany')
        text = text.replace('PO', 'Poland')
        text = text.replace('SG', 'Singapore')
        text = text.replace('UK', 'United Kingdom')
        text = text.replace('US', 'United States')
        text = text.replace('DK', 'Denmark')
        text = text.replace('MX', 'Mexico')
        text = text.replace('IT', 'Italy')
});
```

Comment: Chaning `text` won't change the actual content of the DOM. You'll need to call `text()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change a text with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411696/how-to-change-a-text-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
  var text = $(".country div").html();
  text = text.replace('CA', 'Canada')
  text = text.replace('DE', 'Germany')
  text = text.replace('PO', 'Poland')
  text = text.replace('SG', 'Singapore')
  text = text.replace('UK', 'United Kingdom')
  text = text.replace('US', 'United States')
  text = text.replace('DK', 'Denmark')
  text = text.replace('MX', 'Mexico')
  text = text.replace('IT', 'Italy');
            
  $(".country div").html(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="country">
  <span class="section-label">Country/Region</span>
  <div>IT DE CA US</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.